# Java no reconoce la instrucción System.out.println(); en el ámbito de mi clase

Tags: java

Buen día, tengo un problema con mi proyecto y es que al escribir sout, no me permite autocompletar, y si lo quiero hacer manualmente, al escribir System.out.print(""); no me lo reconoce y me marca error, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Colócalo dentro de un método y no a nivel de clase. También deberías leer como hacer una pregunta y no poner el código en una imagen.

Comment: @DiegoLoL esta es la respuesta correcta. Ponla en una respuesta y no en los comentarios.

Comment: Gracias @E.Betanzos pero es una respuesta demasiado escueta. A ver si el OP edita su pregunta, y hacemos algo con ello. :)

Comment: @DiegoLoL no importa si es escueta, lo importante es que solucione el problema del OP

Answer (score 5):

Cuando defines una **[clase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clase_(inform%C3%A1tica))**, declaras las características y comportamientos de una **[instancia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instancia_(inform%C3%A1tica))**.

- Las características son **[variables de instancia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_de_instancia)**.
- Los comportamientos son **[métodos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_(inform%C3%A1tica))**.

Por esta razón, Java no **reconocerá** una **instrucción** que esté por **fuera de sus estándares**.

La instrucción de **salida estándar de Java** está compuesta por:

- **System** es una clase.
- **out** es una instancia.
- **println();** es un método **sin retorno** (void).

Carece de sentido darle una utilidad en el [ámbito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81mbito_(programaci%C3%B3n)) de clase, este no seria ejecutado en ningún momento por el programa, por lo tanto el **[IDE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entorno_de_desarrollo_integrado)** marcará un **error de compilación**.

Pero, si puedes llamar a un método que tenga un tipo de retorno, ejemplo:

```
int result = methodTest();

public int methodTest(){
    return 0;
}
```

Es válido, ya que se estaría **inicializando** una variable, tiene un sentido de utilidad.

Pero, en cambio:

```
methodTest(); //Error de compilación

public int methodTest(){
    return 0;
}
```

Arrojaría un error de compilación al igual que un método sin retorno, porque también carece de sentido su utilidad.

Conclusión:

1. Una clase está compuesta por **instrucciones de declaración**.
2. `System.out.println();` No es una instrucción de declaración.

Answer (score 0):

Mete el

```
System.out.println("Tu mensaje");
```

dentro de un método

Comment: Además de publicar código, deberías explicar por qué el código responde a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes utilizar la clase System afuera de un método es una definición ilegal, tampoco es una clase instanciable.

Te dejo un ejemplo clásico:

```
public class HolaMundo{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("¡Hola mundo!");
    }
}
```

En tu caso puedes utilizarlo dentro de tu constructor:

```
public Pantalla(){

  System.out.println("");

}
```